# vector push_back a moved local var in c++11 , test and confuse

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, move-semantics

The following test is compiled in g++ 4.8.1

```
int main()
{
    vector<string> v ;
    v.push_back("33333") ;
    v.push_back("44444") ;
    v.push_back("55555") ;

    {
        string x("xxxxx") ;
        v.push_back(x) ; //copy 
        cout << "x=" << x << endl ; //x=xxxxx
    } //checkpoint1

    {
        string y("yyyyy") ;
        v.push_back(std::move(y)) ; //move 
        cout << "y=" << y << endl ; //y=
    } //checkpoint2

    for(auto const i : v)
        cout << i << " " ; 
    cout << endl ; //33333 44444 55555 xxxxx yyyyy 
}
```

It is a quite easy source, my test focus in `std::move`. As you can see, `string x` is local var, while execute `v.push_back(x)`, `x` is copied to vector `v`, so `x` still has `"xxxxx"` after `push_back`. After checkpoint1, `x` is gone (it is local only) but vector `v` has its value since `x` is copied while doing `v.push_back(x)`, so it is ok!!

As for `string y`, it is moved to vector `v` because `std::move` is used, so you can
see `cout << "y=" << y` shows `"y="`, not `"y=yyyyy"`, it is the right behavior.

What I don't get is, after checkpoint2, the string `y`, as a local var has its life end,
so vector `v` as `y`'s owner (because `y` is moved to vector `v` by `push_back(std::move(y))`, should contain an invalid element because `y`, as a stack local var, is life end at checkpoint2!

I am confused that after checkpoint2, vector `v` still have `"yyyyy"`, `y` is moved to vector `v`, if vector `v` just have a pointer `vptr = &y`, since `y` is local var in stack memory, after its scope is out, stack is gone, so vector `vptr` is useless, look like this is not true!

So it must be vector has its own memory to keep `"yyyyy"` in its own, but if this is the
case, it is the same with `push_back(x)`, so why bother has `std::move(y)`?

Do I miss something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can think of a `std::string` kind of like a smart pointer.  The `std::string` variable is pointing to the actual string data which is stored somewhere else.  When you `std::move` a `std::string`, the new string is given a pointer to that data, and the old string is cleared.

Here's a very simple version of how it might work:

```
class MyString {
  public:
    // Move constructor
    MyString(MyString&& that)
      // Just make our string data point to the other string
      : string_data(that.string_data)
    {
      // And make sure the string we are moving from no longer points
      // to that data so it won't get freed when the other string
      // is destructed.         
      that.string_data = 0;
    }

    // Copy constructor
    MyString(const MyString& that)
      // We can't take the other string's data, so we need a copy
      : string_data(new char[strlen(that.string_data)+1])
    {
      strcpy(string_data,that.string_data);
    }

    // Assignment using copy and swap idiom.
    MyString& operator=(MyString that)
    {
      std::swap(string_data,that.string_data);
      return *this;
    }

    ~MyString()
    {
      // string_data may be null if it has been moved from, but
      // that's ok -- it is safe to delete a null pointer.
      delete [] string_data;
    }

  private:
    char *string_data;
};
```

When you move `y` into the vector.  The string data is now part of the string that is owned by the vector, and `y` no longer has anything to do with it.  When `y` goes out of scope, it has no effect on the data in the vector, since `y` no longer has a pointer to it.

Comment: Thank you,Vaughn Cato,may I ask one more question? according to your statement above, std::string is like smart pointer , var y is a local var, its contain "yyyyy" is in somewhere else , after its own is moved to vector , so y is nothing to do with that memory "yyyyy" ever since , vector should take care of that "yyyyy" memory just like normal  smart pointer will do ... Am I correct ?

Comment: @barfatchen: Yeah, indirectly.  The `vector` takes care of memory of the strings it contains, and the strings then take care of the memory that they point to.

Comment: for `std::string`, the small string optimization can make moving for small strings more expensive

Answer (score 0):

A move constructor, just like a copy constructor, involves two objects: (a) an original source object; and (b) a newly created destination object.

In your case the local variable is the source object, and the destination object is a newly created object by `push_back` that is placed in the vectors storage.

The difference between a move constructor and a copy constructor is that by convention the source object may be modified and it isn't expected to be used again (the source object is an "expiring" object).  This allows the classes author to make optimizations that may damage the source object, such as transferring ("moving") resources from the source object to the destination object.

In the case of `std::string`, maybe each string contains a member pointer to a dynamically allocated array.  The move constructor may simply swap the pointer from the source object to the destination object.